# imagemagick not working with php

Tags: php, delegates, imagemagick, postscript

I have installed imagemagick on my windows server and it successfully converted files when i     tried in CMD, but when i use following code in php:-

```
$im = new imagick( 'arc.pdf[0]' );    
$im->setImageColorspace(255);    
$im->setResolution(300, 300);    
$im->setCompressionQuality(95);    
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');    
$im->writeImage('thumb.jpg');    
$im->clear();    
$im->destroy();
```

it gives folowing error:-

> ImagickException: unable to open image `arc.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638 in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 10

I also tried

```
$im = new imagick( 'C:\wamp\www\test\arc.pdf' );    
$im->setImageColorspace(255);    
$im->setResolution(300, 300);    
$im->setCompressionQuality(95);    
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');    
$im->writeImage('thumb.jpg');    
$im->clear();    
$im->destroy();
```

then it gives:-

> ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed `C:\wamp\www\test\arc.pdf':No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/679 in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 10

Comment: Do you have PostScript installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick needs PostScript to read PDF files. That's likely your problem.

Fetch it from here: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html install and try again.

Comment: oh dude thanx a lot, you are my saviour. but still there's a problem converting more then one page.

Comment: its giving following error 
`ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed C:\wamp\www\test\testing.pdf: No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/679 in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 10` .......   
i am using followng code ..............................................................
`$pages=5;
$im = new imagick( 'C:\wamp\www\test\testing.pdf['.$pages.']' ); 
$im->setImageColorspace(255); 
$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->setCompressionQuality(95); 
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg'); 
$im->writeImage('thumbes.png'); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();`

Comment: when i use [0] only first page of pdf is converted, but i need all of them. the pdf file i am using have 5 pages.

Comment: thanx man but i think i have figured it out, i have used following code and all pages are converted to .jpg. thanx for your help man, and if you know any code to count pages of multi-page pdf then plz let me know. thanx.    
`$pages=4;    
for($i=0;$i<=$pages;$i++)    
{
 $im = new imagick( 'C:\wamp\www\test\testing.pdf['.$i.']' );     
 $im->setImageColorspace(255);     
 $im->setResolution(300, 300);    
 $im->setCompressionQuality(95);     
 $im->setImageFormat('jpeg'); 
 $im->writeImage('thumbes'.$i.'.jpg');     
 $im->clear();     
 $im->destroy();    
}`